# how to delete sharepoint workflow from powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, powershell

hi guys i need a help to get easy way to delete work flow from sub site level . its a pain to load it to SPD and do for there since site have lot of work flows .

this Poweshell i got the work flow details .

**$site = Get-SPSite "SITEURL";
$site.AllWebs | foreach { $*.Lists | foreach { $*.WorkflowAssociations | foreach { 
  write-host "Site:" $*.ParentWeb.Url ", List:" $*.ParentList.Title ", Workflow:" $_.Name
} } }**

any help is welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

To remove all Workflow Associations in a Site Collection you can do something like:

```
(Get-SPSite http://sp2010).AllWebs |
  Foreach-Object {
    $wfas = ($_.Lists |
             Select-Object -Expand WorkFlowAssociations | 
             Select-Object Id, ParentList);
    $wfas |
      Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -ne $null) {
          $_.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations.Remove($_.Id)
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To delete the Specific Workflow 

  param(  [string] $env = $(Read-Host  -prompt “Specify the environment you want to run on (D-Dev, T-Test,
  P-Production) :”)

)
 $env = $env.ToLower()
 if($env -ne ‘d’ -and $env -ne ‘t’ -and $env -ne ‘p’)
{
    Write-Host “ERROR:  Invalid Input.”
}
else {
               $siteAddress =  $null
     if($env -eq ‘t’)
 {  $siteAddress = ‘http://test.yoursite.com/’ }

    elseif($env -eq ‘d’) 
{
  $siteAddress = ‘http://dev.yoursite.com/’ }
                elseif($env -eq  ‘p’) { $siteAddress = ‘http://yoursite.com/’ }   

  # Get the SPSite object for a  given SharePoint Url

  $SPSite = Get-SPSite
  $siteAddress

  if($SPSite -ne $null)

  {
         # Get the root  website

    $Web = $SPSite.OpenWeb();
     # Get the list  to which we wanted to associate the workflow
       $SPList  =$Web.Lists[“Announcements”];
                 $workflowAssociation  = $SPList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(“SharePoint Approval
  Workflow”, [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
                 if($workflowAssociation  -ne $null)
                {
                                #  Remove workflow association to list
                                $SPList.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($workflowAssociation);
                                $SPList.Update();
                                Write-Host  “Workflow association removed Successfully.” -foreground color  “Green”
                }
                else
                {
                                Write-Host  “Workflow association could not be found.” -foregroundcolor  “Yellow”
                }
  }
}
```